# $LDL^t$ Factorization Algorithm to find a factorization of the form A

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, matrix-decomposition

For $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        4 & 2 & 2 \\
        2 & 6 & 2 \\
        2 & 2 & 5 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$ I found that $$
        L=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        1/2 & 1 & 0 \\
        1/2 & 1/5 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$ and $$
        D=\begin{pmatrix}
        4 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 5 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 18/5 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
However, when I calculate $LDL^t$, I always get $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        4 & 2 & 2 \\
        2 & 6 & 2 \\
        2 & 2 & 24/5 \\
        \end{pmatrix},
$$ which does not equal to Matrix A.
Did I make a mistake? but 24/5 and 5 are pretty close. Can someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: According to my calculations, it should be $D_{3,3} = \frac{19}{5},$ instead of $18/5$ and $L_{3,3} = 1$. So, could you please check it?

Comment: Sorry I had a typo in my question, but yea you are right! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the algorithm located at [*this site*](http://mathforcollege.com/nm/mws/gen/04sle/mws_gen_sle_txt_cholesky.pdf), you should get:

$$L = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \dfrac{1}{2} & 1 & 0 \\
 \dfrac{1}{2} & \dfrac{1}{5} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$D = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 4 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 5 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \dfrac{19}{5} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Your answer is correct! I must have made some mistake in my calculation. Thanks!!

Comment: Yea I know it has to be a minor mistake cuz $24/5$ and 5 are very very close lol I made mistakes all the time Geez